# Can we get the list of installed apps programmatically in our app in windows phone 8?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

Can we get list of app installed in phone from my app?
I have seen many question here all are saying not possible and few answers saying with live id they're access our App history and showing.

But see how this apps working :

http://www.windowsphone.com/en-us/store/app/app-folder/7d2e7de3-95e7-4143-8a9d-aedf8c3f901e

http://www.windowsphone.com/en-us/store/app/app-folder/1a248adb-1429-45ea-a507-f3d5f4cad58c

And Can we open any app that we installed in our phone from our APP?
For example : - My app need to open "Bing Weather" app.

Thank you

ShareOurIdeas.com

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you can't. That's not possible.

Both apps you linked to are not *standard-apps*. Look at publisher names: **Nokia Corporation** and **SAMSUNG ELECTRONICS Co, Ltd**.

They have different kind of access to system resources then you have as a developer using public Windows Phone API.

Comment: Yes I agree.. At least can we open another app from our app. (with out knowing any URL scheme)

Comment: No, you can't. You can only use launchers to start some actions.